# MVC 4 - populate dropdownlistfor with model list

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate a dropdownlistfor in my view and I don't know the correct lambda expression for it to work. See code below:

```
@model Website.Models.modelTeamSelect


<h2>MatchSelect.cshtml</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_PartialTeams",
    new
    {
        model = this.Model
    },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "divMatchScheduler",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }))
{

    <div id="divMatchScheduler">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelMatch.HomeTeam)
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelMatch.HomeTeam, new SelectList
    {
      Items = Model.teams.Select(t => t.TeamName)  
    })
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelMatch.AwayTeam)

         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelMatch.MatchDate)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelMatch.MatchDate)
    </div>

     <input type="submit" value="Add Match" name="btnSubmit" />


}
```

**This syntax is wrong**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelMatch.HomeTeam, new SelectList
    {
      Items = Model.teams.Select(t => t.TeamName)  
    })
```

**My model being used by the view and the collection it contains**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class modelMatch
    {
       public Guid MatchID { get; set; }

       public Guid AwayTeamID { get; set; }
       public string AwayTeam { get; set; }

       public Guid HomeTeamID { get; set; }
       public string HomeTeam { get; set; }

       public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class modelTeamSelect
    {
        public modelTeamSelect()
        {
            teams = new List<modelTeam>();
            team = new modelTeam();
            modelMatch = new Models.modelMatch();
            modelMatches = new List<modelMatch>();
        }

        public List<modelTeam> teams { get; set; }
        public modelTeam team { get; set; }
        public modelMatch modelMatch { get; set; }
        public List<modelMatch> modelMatches { get; set; }

        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Summary**

How do I populate dropdownlistfor using a list collection that is in my model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most cases you'll want to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `SelectList` to populate your dropdowns.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelMatch.HomeTeam, new SelectList(Model.teams, "dataValueField", "dataTextField"))
```

`dataValueField` and `dataTextField` are the properties from your `modelTeam` model that will be used as value and text for the dropdown.

Comment: I know this post is old but thought it might help someone out. A third option can be added after the data text field to set the selected value.   
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelMatch.HomeTeam, new SelectList(Model.teams, "dataValueField", "dataTextField", "selectedValue"))

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    <br />
    ViewBag.TeamList = Model.teams.Select(t => t.TeamName);
    <br />
}   

<br />

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelMatch.HomeTeam, ViewBag.TeamList as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can create HtmlHelperExtensions class to bind dropdowns.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ObtenerPais(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            var cnx = new db();

            var resultado = cnx.PAIS.ToList()
                .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = e.NOMBRE,
                    Value = Convert.ToString(e.ID_PAIS)
                }).ToList();

            //if (Default)
            resultado.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "-- Seleccionar --",
                Value = ""
            });

            return resultado;
        }
```

And for use it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_ENTIDAD, Html.ObtenerPais(Default: true))
```

Hope this helps